# Query an SQL Datetime Column using only part of the date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

For example I have a column with these dates:

- 2013-05-18
- 2012-06-25
- 2012-07-29
- 2015-08-31

I want to query and return only rows with the year 2012, or month 05.
The issue is that I'm not querying for the whole date but part of it. 
I'm using Entity Framework and C#.

This is what my code looks, it's not linq but it gets the job done.

```
using (var db = new Entity())
{
     foreach (var a in db.table)
     {
          if ((a.dateColumn.Value.Day == day)) //day is an int
          {
             //do stuff
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var x =(from c in db.Table
         where c.Date.Value.Year == 2012
         select c).ToList();
```

And for Month:

```
var y = (from c in db.Table
         where c.Date.Value.Month == 5
         select c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

using lambda expression

```
YourTable.where(x=>x.Date.Year==2013)
YourTable.where(x=>x.Date.Month==5)
```